# How to use Subquery which returned more than one result

Tags: sql, t-sql, subquery

My SQL query

```
UPDATE Task SET Done = 1 WHERE (ID = (SELECT ID FROM User WHERE UserName = @UserName)
```

I tried and got an error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression. The statement has been terminated.

Is there any possible way to do that (for example a for loop)? Thanks

Comment: You have more than one username with the same name? that's sounds weird. Maybe you are forgetting to pass the parameter and you have blanks usernames? (that's still weird?).

Comment: @gbianchi - You are posting that comment on a site that allows duplicate usernames, so it's not actually that weird as a concept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How would a row's ID be equal to more than one value?

That doesn't make sense, which is why writing such a query isn't possible.

Checking if the ID is in a set would make sense, though...

`...WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID...`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `IN` operator.

```
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM User WHERE UserName = @UserName)
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE Task SET Done = 1 WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM User WHERE UserName = @UserName)

Answer (score 0):

How about the following. You can use simple joins the same way you do in SELECT statements:

```
UPDATE Task t, User u 
SET t.Done = 1 
WHERE t.ID = u.ID
AND u.UserName = @UserName
```